# How to divide a string with multiple delimeter, but delimeter is keep include into the array? (VB.NET)

Tags: string, split, vb.net-2010

I have a string:

```
string = "Hello.world, have a nice day"
```

Is there a way to split the string with point or comma as delimeter, but only retain the delimeter into the array? (whitespace is separator but is not retain)

```
['Hello','.','world',',','have','a','nice','day']
```

which delimeter for `regex.split(delimeter)` would be preferable?

and this is my code

`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim arr As String() = Regex.Split(TextBox1.Text, "[.|\,]")
        For Each i As String In arr
            Console.WriteLine(i)
        Next
End Sub`

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split by a dot or a comma, you can update your character class to `[.,]` because the character class would match any of the listed characters.

The character class `[.|\,]` can for example also be written as `[.,|]` and note that you don't have to escape the comma .

The use a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to keep the delimiters.

Your final pattern would look like `([.,])`

See the [vb.net demo](https://ideone.com/91uw13)

For example:

```
Dim s As String = "Hello.world, have a nice day"
Dim arr As String() = Regex.Split(s, "([.,])")
For Each i As String In arr
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

Result:

```
Hello
.
world
,
 have a nice day
```

Comment: oouh thank you, how about remove whitespace if the space is not one times